# Using AWT components inside a JInnerFrame (for JDesktopPane)

Tags: java, swing, awt, jinternalframe

is there a way to hack bugs related to adding an AWT component (in my case a `PApplet`, so a processing language sketch) inside a `JInternalFrame`?

It works but not as intended, since it flickers and dragging the frame causes repaint issues.. reading around it seems that, althrough it's possible to mix heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight (Swing) components some problems seem to be unavoidable.. is it true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently improved, [*Mixing Heavy and Light Components*](http://www.johnloomis.org/cpe101/notes/Swing/heavy-light/heavy-light.html) may shed some light on your particular usage. See also, [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).